# unable to retrieve data selected in view function

Tags: python, django

`
Hi, I am unable to retrieve only data in the view function. Please find the data below :

```
 "data": {
    "id": "63f4625a1393d5ff8037a249",
    "group_name": "Alia",
    "slug": "favorites",
    "parent_id": null,
    "updated_at": null,

     data": {
    "total": 2,
        "media": [
            {
                "id": "63f84927139",
                "group_id": "63f46",
                "content_type": "videos",
                "created_at": "2023"
            },
            {
                "id": "640abd",
                "group_id": "63f4625",
                "content_type": "videos",
                "created_at": "2023"
            }
        ]
    }
},
"status": true
}
```

Here is my view function:

```
def view(request):
    context={}
    context= data    
    context['title'] = 'Favourite data                  
    return render(request, 'admin/data.html',context)
```

When I am printing the data I am getting the whole data but I want to have only media_data. Please assist

Comment: It's going to be `data['data']['media_data']`.

Comment: Hi Tim , also if i need only id of two assets what should i do . Please assist

Comment: Do you know Python?  This is just a normal Python object with dictionaries and lists.

Answer (score 0):

I think `return render(request, 'admin/favourite_data.html',context)['media_data']` should work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have data dict or response as

```
data = {
    "id": "63f4625a1393d5ff8037a249",
    "group_name": "Favorites",
    "slug": "favorites",
    "parent_id": None,
    "updated_at": None,
    "media_data": {
    "totalAssets": 2,
        "media": [
            {
                "id": "63f849271393d5ff8037a2e5",
                "group_id": "63f4625a1393d5ff8037a249",
                "content_type": "videos",
                "created_at": "2023-02-24T05:20:39.461000"
            },
            {
                "id": "640abd2e1393d5ff8037a3cf",
                "group_id": "63f4625a1393d5ff8037a249",
                "content_type": "videos",
                "created_at": "2023-03-10T05:16:30.210000"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

then your context would be as:

```
def test(request):
    context = data
    context['title'] = 'Favourite data'
    print(context['media_data'])
    return render(request, 'favourite_data.html', context)
```

and access it in html as

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
{{ media_data }}
</body>
</html>
```